# Laravel Query/ Relational database query

Tags: laravel

I have two data tables `vehicles` and `trips`, which have a one to many relationship and allow for multiple trips per vehicle. `route` is a column in the `trips` table. I want to see the vehicle list for a specific route, so I ran the following query.

```
$trips = Trip::with('vehicle')
     ->where('route', $route)
     ->get()->pluck('vehicle');
```

It work's fine, returns a vehicle collection. Now that I have the vehicle collection I want the active trip information with every vehicle model. I tried the following query.

```
$trips = Trip::with('vehicle', ['vehicle.activeTrip' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('status', 0);
        }])
        ->where('route', $route)
        ->get()->pluck('vehicle');
```

`status = 0` indicates an active trip. But it is unsuccessful anyway. I got an error with the message `Method name must be a string`. Can anyone assist me in resolving my problem?

Comment: are `trip` and `activeTrip` actually different tables?

Comment: Actually same table but different relationship, for active trip I use `one to one` relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you use this syntax

```php
$trips = Trip::with(['vehicle','vehicle.activeTrip' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('status', 0);
        }])
        ->where('route', $route)
        ->get()->pluck('vehicle');
```

Comment: Yeah, it's working, I made that silly mistake.

Comment: @ShahFoyez oh nice, please rate the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I just came across another solution. To retrieve the active trip data, we could use the Laravel `ofMany` method inside the `Trip` model.

```
public function activeTrip(){
return $this->hasOne(Trip::class, 'vid')->ofMany([], function ($query) {
    $query->where('status', 0);
});}
```